# Trying to get a price in Selenium using Java inside an app-item-box

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to get a price inside an app-item-box using selenium wiht JAVA. There are six app-item-boxs on the web page. I need to get the correct app-item-boxs price that matches a certain name. The name I need is the app-item-box with the img call M4A4 | asiimov (Field-Tested). And the price I need to get is 118.04. I have used selenium many times and am experienced enough. I normally use it with IDs and class names. But I havn't come acrros anything like this and its all new to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: `ngcontent` means angular website, this may not work with selenium webdriver, you may require `ngWebdriver` or `webdriver.io`

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the reply. That makes sense why none of my selenium would work. i will take a look at ngWebdriver. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first reach the `alt=M4A4` element and then can use `following` in the xpath to reach its price.
You can do it like:

```
// Fetch the element
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@alt,'M4A4')]//following::div"));
//Fetch its price by using getText method
String price = element.getText();
```